# set the choices of ChoiceField in Django Rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

using Django 2.0 with Rest 3.7.7.

I have a **Serializer** class where a field is a **ChoiceField** and it's choices are the result of calling a function which takes the **request.user** as argument.

Here's my code:

```
class PostModelCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    group    = serializers.ChoiceField(choices='')
    # What I want to do is this
    # group    = serializers.ChoiceField(choices= request.user.get_groups())
    # get_groups() returns a queryset of groupModel
    class Meta:
        model = MYMODEL
        fields=[
        'id',
        'group',
        'content'
        ]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To get current user you can use `self.context['request'].user` syntax. To validate if provided group is in user's groups list you can create `validate_group` method:

```
class PostModelCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MYMODEL
        fields=[
        'id',
        'group',
        'content'
        ]

    def validate_group(self, value):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        user_groups = user.get_groups()
        if value not in user_groups:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Invalid group")
        return value
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
but the function validate_group() is not called at all
You deleted the group    = serializers.ChoiceField(choices='')
but I tried with both ways (with the line you deleted and without it)

Comment: @CHEMSEDDINEHAROUIT does `group` defined as model field?

Comment: I don't want it as a model field, 
If I make it as a modelField, I'll have to fill all fields of group in the form of creating a post (PostModelCreateSerializer)

Comment: @CHEMSEDDINEHAROUIT Try to use `Serializer` class instead of 
 `ModelSerializer` in this case. `ModelSerializer` preffered with fields that correspond to the Model fields.Example of `Serializer` class usage: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances

Comment: @neverwalkanloner , I'd like to, but I have other fields needing a `ModelSerializer` like `user`, 

*I didn't mention it just because I don't want to encumber the post*


I appreciate your help sir

Comment: I wanted to use `serializers.SerializerMethodField()` and then set the display to a `ChoiceField` and then give it the choices in `get_group()`

Comment: @CHEMSEDDINEHAROUIT I dont think it will work. `SerializerMethodField` is read-only. So I suppose you cannot post data using it. Not able to test it right now. Please let me know if it will work.

Comment: sure, I will sir